# Won't wake up from sleep mode / password not accepted (Ubuntu 18.04.3)

Tags: 18.04, login, suspend, password

After a search on the web, it seems that I am not the only one having trouble waking up my computer from sleep, and having to reboot. However, my issue seems to be different:

- I have Ubuntu 18.04.3
- At this day, I am up to date
- When I try to wake up my computer, I have the login screen, but it takes one or 2 minutes before saying that the password is wrong, sometimes I have a black screen during the 2 minutes wait, and then I can not type anything in the password field. Typing CTRL+ALT+F1 goes back to the user choice screen, typing CTRL+ALT+F2 goes to the login screen. If I try to enter the password, same story (wait a while, nothing happen, then says that the pass is wrong, then I cannot type). CTRL+ALT+F3 allows me to login in text mode, but I can not really do much more.
- When I log out from my session (so without using the lock screen symbol), I can login again.

Does anyone knows about this problem ? I am not an expert, and I definitely need some help. Let me know if you need more information about my system.

Many thanks in advance for your time,

K.

Comment: Same here. Can not login after recovering from sleep mode. The password is correct, but it returns to the login manager.

Comment: Login user another account works. This might be a problem with the account settings/Xorg permissions/gnome shell.